# MULTIPLYING an array ELEMENT in while loop ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, class, operators

I have an array of integers, and I am attempting to multiply every second element by 2 moving backwards in the array. However, it does not seem to accept the * operator on the array item, results in the error message:  undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
 index = array.length
  while index > 0
    array[index] * 2
    index - 2
  end
```

I have checked the class of the array items and it is indeed an integer, so I am unsure why this does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the value of your `array[index] * 2` and `index - 2` expressions, you need to assign them to something: `array[index] *= 2`, `array[index] = array[index] * 2`, `index = index - 2`, `index -= 2`, ...

Comment: tried doing that, still results in " undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: it is an array of integers: 
[4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]

Comment: your index should be `array.length - 1` (remember, arrays are 0-indexed). Also you are not doing anything with `array[index] * 2` (either print it, or assign to a variable)

Comment: With an input array of `[4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]`, what did you expect the output to be? I had interpreted the phrase "every second element" to mean the result should be `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]`. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate reversed array with indexes, and then reverse result [Array#reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse)
`i % 3` is used to multiply each 3rd element.

Error `undefined method *' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` in your example appears because `array.length` is 16(elements in array), but indexes starts from 0, so last index is 15, and in the first iteration you are trying to access array[16] that does not exist, so it is `nil`

```
array = [4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]
result = array.reverse.each_with_index.map do |x, i|
  (i % 3).zero? ? x * 2 : x
end.reverse
# p result
#=> [8, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 8, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 8, 2, 4, 4]
```

UPDATE: `Sekalf Nroc`'s answer is good with `odd?` if you need each 2nd element to multiply, but if you had for example 15 elements, you could see unexpected results, so `reverse` still needed to walk array backwards, by combining those approaches, you can do something like this:

```
array = [4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 99]
p array.map.with_index { |n, i| i.odd? ? n * 2 : n } # WRONG RESULT
#=>[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 99]
p array.reverse.map.with_index { |n, i| i.even? ? n * 2 : n }.reverse
#=>[8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 198]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the indexing as others have suggested, and change the third and fourth lines to actually modify the array and index variables, then your code works as intended for any array with an even number of elements.

```
index = array.length - 1
while index > 0
  array[index] *= 2
  index -= 2
end

# array now =='s [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Alternatively, you could perform the operation in one line using `map.with_index` by taking advantage of the fact that every second element of an array will have an index that is an odd number.

```
array.map.with_index { |n, i| i.odd? ? n * 2 : n }
# Or if you prefer,
array.map.with_index { |n, i| if i.odd? then n * 2 else n end }

#=> [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Range, which provides the [Range#step](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Range.html#method-i-step) method. For example, given the array:

```
ary = [4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]
```

This is a way for "multiply every second element by 2 moving backwards in the array" using [Array#reverse_each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each):

```
(1...ary.size).step(2).each { |i| ary.size.odd? ? ary[i] *=2 : ary[i-1] *=2 }
#=> [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Note that the first part `(1...ary.size).step(2).to_a` returns the odd indexes:

```
#=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Also note the three points `...` in range.

For `ary = [2, 4, 2] #=> [2, 8, 2]`

For `ary = [2, 4, 2, 4] #=> [4, 4, 4, 4]`

Comment: Nice approach, but its not a universal solution, try with  `[2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]`

Comment: @YuriyVerbitskiy, thanks. Fixed, I misinterpreted the OP. Even if I have one more doubt.

Comment: I tried Numeric#step and added a new answer, it looks like better way for use it in this case

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, that uses [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step).
It works good with all the examples even with another step(array3)

```
array1 = [4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]
array2 = [2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2]
array3 = [2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2]

(array1.size - 1).step(0, -2).each { |i| array1[i] *= 2 }
(array2.size - 1).step(0, -2).each { |i| array2[i] *= 2 }
(array3.size - 1).step(0, -3).each { |i| array3[i] *= 2 }

p array1, array2, array3
#=>[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
#=>[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
#=>[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```